# Parallel execution of module under always block

Tags: verilog

I have written a module in Verilog implementing a D flip-flop, like the following:

```
module d_flip_flop(q,d,clk,reset);
```

Now, I want to implement a 4-bit shift register using this module.  So I have to execute four d flip flops in parallel inside `always @(negedge clk)` block.  I don't know how to parallel execute four user defined modules inside `always` (or how to instantiate). I don't want a direct behavioral implementation of a 4-bit shift register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create 4 instances, connecting the `q` output of one to the `d` input of the next:

```
wire [3:0] q;
d_flip_flop i0 (q[0], din , clk,reset);
d_flip_flop i1 (q[1], q[0], clk,reset);
d_flip_flop i2 (q[2], q[1], clk,reset);
d_flip_flop i3 (q[3], q[2], clk,reset);
```

There is no need to use an `always` block.